# Search query through foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to search through my comments on the username connected to the user_id Foreign Key

Tables: 
Comment- id, comment, user_id, timestamps
User - id, name, username

Models:

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $comments = Comment::query()->orderby('created_at', 'DESC');

    $id=$request->]


    return view('comments.index')->withComment($comment);
}
```

View:

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'comments.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {!! Form::label('id', 'Search By ID:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('id', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {!! Form::label('username', 'Search By Username:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {!! Form::submit('Find Comments', array('class' => 'btn btn-send ')) !!}
                </div>
                {!!Form::close()!!}

            </div>
@foreach($comment as $comments)
//data
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why is one of them $comments->where(col,val) and the other is $comments->where(col, operator, val) ?  Does that work?

Comment: the only one that doesnt work is this line of code:  $comments->where($comments->author->username, 'LIKE', $request->input('username') )->get()

Comment: Does ->get() populate $comments, or does it return to oblivion because there's no $collection = $... ->get();

Comment: The issue is with the getting the username through relationship not the get

Comment: @Watercayman 's code is more like what I'm used to seeing ~ and then just make sure your users table has a username column or your user model has getUsernameAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is failing at the builder level because you are trying to query on an object that is not yet known.  IE the author LIKE must be part of a sub query:

```
$comments = Comment::whereHas('author', function ($query) use($request) {
    $query->where(users.username, 'LIKE', $request->input('username') )
}])->orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

I see you will have to write the query a second time, but I think this may be successful for you.

Comment: Get an error saying that username doesnt exist in the comment table, which is true. Even if i use 'author.username'

Comment: Sorry - the relation is on users, right?  Try with users.username - i edited to reflect.

Comment: the relation name is author which associates the user to the comment

Comment: Yes, but the relationship is to the users table, which I assume has a username column.  Did the above edit work?

Comment: sorry yes thats correct. either way it still throws errors unfortunately

Comment: OK, if same error, it may be that one of the comments doesn't have an author.  I edited slightly to account for this.  Try now?

Comment: all have an author. Your answer will not work due to multiple queries see OP